# Assigning color to client (Networked)

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

I have been struggling with this for so long now I've forgotten how to write code.

All I'm trying to do is assign a newly spawned client a random color, which is replicated to all clients on the server (and stays consistent).

Here's my code:

```
 public void FindRandomColor()
{
    children = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
    col = new Color(Random.Range(0.1f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.1f, 1.0f), Random.Range(0.1f, 1.0f));

    foreach (Renderer child in children)
    {
        child.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = col;
    }
}

void AssignColorToClient()
{
    if(isLocalPlayer)
    playerSetup.FindRandomColor();
}

void Start () {
    rB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    playerSetup = GetComponent<PlayerSetup>();

    AssignColorToClient();

}
```

Each client does have a color assigned to them, but each client cannot see each others assigned colors. I've fiddled around with [ClientRPC] and [Command] but neither have worked out for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To synchronize the players colour over the network you'll have to use a syncvar

```
[SyncVar(hook = "OnChangeColour")]
public Color col;
```

Then create a hook that listens to changes on the players colour

```
void OnChangeColour (Color col)
{
    child.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = col;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks heaps. Totally did not know about SyncVar's. I haven't managed to get it working just yet - but this is definitely what I was looking for.